# Symfony3 : Warning:copy([...]Entity/User.php~): Permission denied

Tags: php, mysql, unix, permissions, symfony

The exact error is the following

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException] Warning:copy(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Project/src/MR/UserBundle/Entity/User.php~): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

on my Symfony3 command :

```
 'php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities'
```

Does anyone ever had this warning ? or see what may cause the problem ?

I don't know if it's related to that, but I made a terrible mistake this morning, 'rm'ving my User directory (on OS X) with -R option.. a nightmare. I had to reinstall mysql, and did the same with MAMP. My symfony project was intact because of its location in the 'htdocs' directory.

I had the same problem with my var/ directory but solved it with [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup) from the official website.

Hoping for a solve, because I cannot work on the project now..

Thanks in advance !

Comment: well, i've never seen that warning, but *google* has. but it seems that you've simply failed to correctly set access rights in your file system after reinstalling.

Comment: I came to the stage of making 'chmod -R 0777' on the entire project.. (I am just working on my local), without any success

Comment: have you tried completely wiping MAMP? uninstalling, deleting the whole folder and every file associated and reinstalling it?

Comment: I did (using AppCleaner). Let's do it another time, I may have missed a step

Comment: It works fine that time, Thank you ! (because I was not thinking of doing it again). The only thing is that I do not see my database, even if I can connect to phpMyAdmin, and even after creating it. (I use datafixtures in order to populate my database)

Answer (score 1):

When Symfony generates entities, it makes a backup, and in your case the file it is backing up is called 'User.php~'. So for some reason when you run the command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities
```

It doesn't have permission to write to that particular folder. Maybe do you have to use `sudo`? Or maybe you have to login as a different user? Regardless, it's a permission problem of writing the backup file.

By the way, the new file would be 'User.php', and the backup once the command completes is renamed 'User.php~'.

Hope this helps.